# Avoid repeating method from constructor and ngOnInit

Tags: angular

I have a app service to interact between various components.
When I click to client name from dashboard, It takes me to detail page.
Also on the same details page I have list of clients on right side panel.
when I click on any client name from right side panel is shows client detail on the same page using below emitter.

Can someone help me to find out how can I avoid repeating of initMethod() from tow places.

note: when I emit some value from this.appService.appEmittedId$ is not executing my initMethod() from **ngOnInit()**.

```
constructor() {
this.appService.appEmittedId$.subscribe(id => {
  if (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.clId = this.appService.clid;
    this.initMethod();
  }
});
}

ngOnInit() {
this.id = this.appService.id;
this.initMethod();
this.clid = this.appService.clid;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is no need to place the subscription in the `constructor`. You can, but it is not considered a good practice. For that is the `OnInit` life cycle hook.

You can initialize your 'tasks' like so:

```
ngOnInit {
  this.appService.appEmittedId$.subscribe(id => {
  if (id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.clId = this.appService.clid;
    this.initMethod();
  }
 });
}
```

No aditional code required.

Use the constructor for injecting services.